# Генерация path segment страницы из .ini файла

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Есть страница сайта, например, "xxx.yyy.zzz/1 name". И есть ini-файл, где прописано code="name1"

Когда идёт генерация пути к странице, то веб берёт название папки в качестве path segment страницы. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при генерации пути в качестве path segment веб брал значение code из ini-файла, чтобы конечный путь к странице получался как "xxx.yyy.zzz/name1"

Как такое можно реализовать?